# Can anyone comment on this proof for products of sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am working on this (http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/assignments/MIT6_436JF08_hw01.pdf) and it's pretty hard.  I really want to be able to have my work critiqued since it's so hard to know if I am doing things right or wrong.  So here is my attempt at exercise #2:

Given: $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x , \{y_n\} \rightarrow y$

This means that: $\exists N_x,\epsilon_x, N_y, \epsilon_y$ S.T

$|x_k - x| < \epsilon_x \forall k>N_x$  And,

$|y_k-y| < \epsilon_y \forall k > N_y$

$Let \space N = max\{N_x, N_y\}$

$And \space take \space some \space k>N$

$|x_ky_k - xy| = |y_k(x_k - x) + x(y_k - y)|$

Triangle inequality $\le|y_k(x_k - x)| + |x(y_k - y)|$

$< |y_k\epsilon_x| + |x\epsilon_y| \space  Since \space |x_k - x| < \epsilon_x \space and \space |y_k - y| < \epsilon_y$

$Just \space let \space \epsilon = |y_k \epsilon_x| + |x\epsilon_y| \space and \space the \space result \space follows$

Is this a good place to post this type of question?  Are there other communities that are made for posting and critiquing other people's work?

Comment: You need to find a positive integer $N$ such that $k>N$ implies $|x_ky_k-xy|<\epsilon$. Why are you letting $\epsilon$ equal something?

Comment: Because $|y_k\epsilon_k| + |x\epsilon_y|$ can be made arbitrarily small since $\epsilon_x$ and $\epsilon_y$ can be made arbitrarily small.  But it depends on k which I guess is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to find an upper bound for $y_k$ and this is not difficult at all, I'm not sure if you know that every convergent sequence is bounded if not the proof is pretty easy, (Hint: Let $\varepsilon=1$ and use the definition of convergent, the finite case can be solved by induction). With this you find an upper bound $M$ for all $y_k$, i.e., $|y_k|\le M$.

Our task is given a $\varepsilon>0$ to find a $N_\varepsilon$ such that $|y_kx_k-yx|\le \varepsilon$. Then if you choose $\varepsilon'= \min(\varepsilon/2(M+1),\varepsilon/2(|x|+1))$ and $|x_k-x|\le \varepsilon'$ and $|y_k-y|\le \varepsilon'$ this is possible because are convergent to $x$ and $y$ respectively.  Since you have for all $k\ge N_{\varepsilon'}$:

\begin{align} |y_k||x_k-x|+|x||y_k-y|\le M |x_k-x|+|x||y_k-y|\\
\le  M\frac{\varepsilon}{2(M+1)}+|x|\frac{\varepsilon}{2(|x|+1)}\\
\le\varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2\\
\le \varepsilon\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

In this question you are supposed to find a number $N$ such that $\forall k>N, |x_k y_k-x y|<\epsilon$ starting from given that $x_k$ and $y_k$ converges to $x$ and $y$ respectively and some $\epsilon>0$.

And also $x_k$ converges to $x$ means $$\forall \epsilon >0\ \exists N\in \mathbb{N},\ |x_k - x|<\epsilon$$

Note that definition says $\forall \epsilon>0$ but you proof says $\exists \epsilon$.